# Using istringstream() to distinguish between "0" and non-numerical string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make a program to play poker. When betting the player should enter an integer number as their new bet. To prevent errors when someone mistypes and enters a string the code is intended to take in a string, check if it is a number, and if it is not then ask the player to enter a valid bet.

The code below is my attempt at making a function to do that using the istringstream function to convert the string betstring to an int.

istringstream returns 0 if the string has no number in it. betstring is an invalid entry if it is a number less than 0 or if it contains no numbers. If betstring is "0" this is a valid bet.

If betstring is mixed letters and numbers (e.g. j96kp) then this "j96kp" is assumed to indicate a bet of 96 for simplicity so it is valid.

The problem comes when I enter a betstring equal to "0". The code interprets this as an invalid bet. I have checked the logic operators and I do not understand why the code does not take "0" to be a valid bet.

Can anybody spot where the problem is arising?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int requestBet()
{
    int newbet;
    string betstring;
    int validbet = 0;
    while(!validbet)
    { //loop until a valid bet is entered
        cin >> betstring;
        validbet = 1; //assume bet is valid then test this
        istringstream(betstring) >> newbet; 
        if(((newbet == 0) && (betstring.at(0) != 0)) || (newbet < 0))
        {
            cout << "Enter a valid bet" << endl;
            validbet = 0;
        }
    }
    return newbet;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter your bet" << endl;
    number = requestBet();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`betstring.at(0) != 0` does not do what you probably expect it to do. You want to compare characters, that is, see if the first character is `'0'`, so you have to put that in there. As it is, your code sees whether the fist char has the numerical value zero (which would be '\0').

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what the problem was! I will "accept" this answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

> ... the player should enter an integer number as their new bet. To prevent errors when someone mistypes and enters a string the code is intended to take in a string, check if it is a number, and if it is not then ask the player to enter a valid bet.

Something like the following will work for you.

```
template <class T>
T StringToValue(const std::string& str) {
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    T value; iss >> value;

    // Use fail(), not bad()
    if (iss.fail())
        throw std::runtime_error("'" + str +"' is not a value");

    return value;   
}
```

You can use it like:

```
string betstring;
cin >> betstring;

int bet;
bet = StringToValue<int>(betstring);
```

If the string is not a presentation of type `T` (`int`, `float`, etc), then a `runtime_error` is thrown.

If you switch to `bad()`, then the function will return 0 when it encounters something that would throw under `fail()`.